# SQL Server 2008 - Delete data exclusively from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to stop power users from deleting data using SQL Server Management Studio. I need to archive data and add some info to the audit trail when data gets deleted.

- Is there a way to stop them when they attempt to delete the data from SSMS?
- Is there a way to know which process caused the deletion? such as from SSMS, application, stored proc?
- Is there a way to allow only deletes from Stored Procedure?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new login and database user for this login. Then grant delete permission to this user, and revoke it from all others. Write procedure[s] that removes data, add `WITH EXECUTE AS [previously created user that can delete data]`. Grant other users with execute permissions to the procedure[s].

Comment: I will give this a try. It seems like a way to go...I do need to give them a way to delete, thus stored proc will be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Well they are power users aren't they. You could set deny Delete permissions for them.

```
DENY DELETE TO [Your_User]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

From your second sentence I get the impression that deleting is not the real issue but that you need to archive data and create an audit trail when data is deleted. Why not use a delete trigger?

Comment: yes, the end goal is to archive data but I need to insert some additional information that I will be passing from the application and it will not be available to delete trigger. If I use stored proc, I can pass it on as an input parameter.